# iOS Color Aberration / Color Fringing Effect

Tags: ios, ios8, core-image

Trying to think of a way to create color aberration (also known as color fringing) effect in black and white images on iOS but i can't figure out how. I want to create the Before effect [image: as seen on this image].

Images will be passed through a filter chain with CIMaximumComponent or CIMinimumComponent for the black and white effect.

Is color aberration doable with Core Image filters? Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if you have finally realize this effect, I also come up with the same problem.:)